# Google Vision API - Access Denied on files in my bucket

Tags: api, access-denied, google-cloud-vision, bucket

I have the following problem with the Google Vision API accessing my bucket files.

Steps:

1. Server to Server OAuth2 with service account for file uploads --> Scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
2. Uploading files to my bucket (no ACL active, activated public access for testing) --> files uploaded successful
3. Server to Server OAuth2 with service account for Vision processing --> Scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
4. Starting Vision Job (https://eu-vision.googleapis.com/v1/files:asyncBatchAnnotate)

Response:

- 403
- Error opening file: gs://mybucketname/myfile.tif
- PERMISSION_DENIED

Service account is the same for both OAuth2 requests.
Both OAuth2 requests were successful und returns an AccessToken.
Vision API is activated.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Best regards!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue and could only solve it by using cloud-platform scope. With just cloud-vision and devstorage.read_write it's still missing something, I'm not sure what.

Comment: Hi, thank you - that solved my issue! Adding the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (View and manage your data across Google Cloud Platform services) was the "trick". I thought it was für management and not for processing.

Comment: ...and unfortunately I have not found any other solution so far. Even after multiple requests to Google in various places, there was no support or suggested solution.

Comment: If you like, you are welcome to post your comment as a solution. I would then be happy to accept it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue and could only solve it by using cloud-platform scope. With just cloud-vision and devstorage.read_write it's still missing something, I'm not sure what.